# Unable to load image with image library

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to load an image from the web and into an image variable that I can use with the image Library: https://pub.dev/packages/image

```
var coverData = 'images/map3a.png';


//img.Image? mapImage;

img.Image? setImageBytes(imageBytes) {
  print("setImageBytes");
  List<int> values = imageBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
  mapImage = null;
  mapImage = img.decodeImage(values);

  return mapImage;
}

late img.Image? mapImage = setImageBytes(coverData);

late var rows = 2 + mapImage!.height;//Y
late var columns = 2 + mapImage!.width;//X
```

When I try displaying rows or columns in a widget, I get the following error.

So far I've tried various different methods from online sources with no avail. I have a friend who is having problems with this aswell and he can't find anything either. If it were to work, the code would display 514 (Height or Length + 2)

Comment: can you include the error widget  you are getting ?

Comment: children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Text:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$rows',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Image.asset(
                'images/map3a.png',

              ),
            ),
          ],